# Error while passing value with url to django view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Error while passing value to view from template using url

Error :

```
Error during template rendering

In template D:\TONO\DJANGO_TASK\user_auth\templates\auth_app\other-user-listing.html, error at line 114
Reverse for 'add_to_group' with arguments '(name: Administrator,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['auth_app\\/<str:username>/']
```

This my urls.py

> ```
> url(r'^<str:username>/', views.add_to_group, name="add_to_group"),
> ```

This is the call from template

```
<a href="{% url 'add_to_group' username  %}"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url defines a **named** argument for the url "add_to_group". You should pass this argument as a keyword argument

```
{% url 'add_to_group' username=username  %}
```

You are mixing the new and old style urls. To use the new style you should use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.path)

```
path('<str:username>/', views.add_to_group, name="add_to_group"),
```

Comment: You're also mixing old and new style urls. You should be using `path`

Comment: i am using urls with python 3.6

Comment: i mean, i am using url instead of path ....................................................                                                                            
                                                                                                           
  urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^function$',views.function,name="function"),
    url(r'^load_home$', views.load_home, name="load_home"),
    url(r'^load_login$', views.load_login, name="load_login"),]

Answer (score 0):

In your call from template see if you do this if that solves the problem, I remember I was facing this issue and this is what I did:

The syntax for specifying `url is {% url namespace:url_name %}`. So, check if you have added the `app_name in urls.py`.

Comment: How to add app_name in urls.py

Comment: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: '/auth_app' is not a registered namespace

Comment: you do:

**app_name: "some name"**

Here's is an example of what one of my urls.py looks like!



`from django.urls import path
from . import views

**app_name = "algorithms"**
urlpatterns = [
        path("posts/", views.blog_index, name="blog_index")
]`

make sure you include the app_name in your project URL as namespace="app_name"

Comment: Here's how my main urls.py look like:

`path("all_posts/", include("explain_algorithms.algo_explained.urls", namespace = "algorithms")),
`

Answer (score 0):

Error corrected using :

```
url(r'^auth_app/add_to_group/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.add_to_group, name='add_to_group'),
```